# Windows cluster и создание постоянно доступного файлового ресурса

Tags: windows, windows-server, share, cluster

Здравсвуйте. Строю кластер на Windows Server 2012R2. Диски подключенны по iSCSI. Пытаюсь создать файловый ресурс с постоянной доступностью, но при создании вылетает ошибка:

```
Произошла ошибка при обновлении общего ресурса SMB: Такой запрос не поддерживается.
```

В чем может быть проблема? В логах пусто.